What do I get if I keep doing synthetic division without an end?
Suppose that I use synthetic division to divide polynomial $f(x)$ by polynomial $g(x)$,  where the constant term in $g(x)$ is non-zero. If I do not stop the division algorithm even if the remainder has a lower degree than $g(x)$, I would get additional numbers. What do these extras represent? Are they related to coefficients of some series?
Context: This is a question I encountered when a high-school student "overran" his synthetic division in an exercise.
My attempt: I tried some examples like $\frac{1}{x-2}$ and $\frac{-x+1}{x^2-2x-1}$ and found that these extra coefficients seeming to relate to Maclaurin series. But sometimes they show up in denominators, and sometimes they have alternating signs. And I don't know what the pattern is.

Update:
Thank you for all the comments. Here I add some details of the above two examples:

Example $\frac{1}{x-2}$:





1









$\mathbf{2}$

2
4
8
16
$\cdots$


----
----
----
----
----
----
----



1
2
4
8
16
$\cdots$



The coefficient list I got is $$1,2,4,8,16,32,\dots$$
As @rogerl, @roundsquare pointed out in the comments, this is $$\frac{1}{x-2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{x^{k+1}}.$$

Example $\frac{-x+1}{x^2-2x-1}$:






$\mathbf{-1}$
$\mathbf{1}$










$\mathbf{1}$


$-1$
$-1$
$-3$
$-7$
$-17$


$\mathbf{2}$


$-2$
$-2$
$-6$
$-14$
$-34$
$\cdots$


----
----
----
----
----
----
----
----
----




$-1$
$-1$
$-3$
$-7$
$-17$
$-41$
$\cdots$



The coefficient list I got is $$-1,-1,-3,-7,-17,-41,\dots$$
@Ted Shifrin (and @rogerl) commented that I need to make clear whether my result is a Laurent series with negative exponents or power series with nonnegative exponents. I think that was where I failed previously -- I only tried to compare with coefficients  with non-negative exponents; but from the  examples, the coefficients match Laurent series with negative exponents.

Can you do out an example please

So instead of dividing $1$ by $x-1$, you divide $1$ by $1-x$ and then take the negative?

$1=0(x-2)+1$. How do you get something that doesn't terminate?

@JohnDouma I think you "take the procedure too far". So, for example, $1/(x - 2) = x^{-1} + 2x^{-2} + 4x^{-3} + \cdots$

For $\frac{1}{x-2}$, you get the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{x^{k+1}}$, which sums to $\frac{1}{x-2}$. I didn't compute the other one; perhaps you can post what you get.

I would get... impatient.

You clearly need to make it clear whether your result is a Laurent polynomial (with infinitely many negative powers of $x$) or a power series (with only nonnegative powers of $x$). Both are correct expansions.

The coefficients in the second one are $(-1, -1, -3, -7, -17, -41, -99, ...)$, which are the numerators of the convergents to $\sqrt{2}$. I do not see why. (The roots of the denominator are $1\pm\sqrt{2}$).

As @TedShifrin pointed out, these are the Laurent series of the functions at $x=0$.

Oops. Laurent series, not Laurent polynomial.
